# How to get/overwrite the styles defined inside the styles.xml (or any other default Xamarin style files) from outside the Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have an app that can be styled for different customers. I use the styles.xml to style the app for each customer. However,  I need to compile the app, every time I need to change the styles. I want to avoid this by getting these style definition from an outside file configuration, and then apply them at run time. I´m already doing this for other resources like images and texts/labels.

Is this possible? How?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example for a color.

If a style has `<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Color1}" />`, then that refers to a Resource with key `Color1`.

In App.xaml.cs, read the config, use it to construct a Color instance. then set that Resource:

```cs
Color color1 = ...;
Application.Current.Resources["Color1"] = color1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already use that method for changing some resources. Let me clarify. My issue is for example for resources like "android:colorPressedHighlight" that are specified in the styles.xml in the Android project. Those resources i dont know how to change in runtime.

Comment: See if it can be controlled by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is for example for resources like "android:colorPressedHighlight" that are specified in the styles.xml in the Android project.

The `ColorPressedHighlight` field is const. It is Compile time constant and could not assign value at runtime.

MS official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.resource.attribute.colorpressedhighlight?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12